# Algorithm or tool in python to distinguish between gibberish/errors and foreign words/names?

Tags: python, nltk

I'm doing some machine extraction of sometimes-garbled PDF text, which often ends up with words incorrectly split up by spaces, or chunks of words put in incorrect order, resulting in pure gibberish.

I'd like a tool that can scan through and recognize these chunks of pure gibberish while skipping non-dictionary words that are likely to be proper names or simply words in a foreign language.

Not sure if this is even possible, but if it is I imagine something like this could be done using NLTK. I'm just wondering if this has been done before to save me the trouble of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: By mentioning foreign names are you indicating implicitly that you have unsuccessfully tried using probability/distribution-based methods? (E.g. dictionary-based trigraph probability matrices)

Comment: No, just that I know that, for example, ilman is not a word in English but isn't gibberish.

Comment: That would be even harder for languages that follow a different orthography. Welsh would be a good example of a language that looks like gibberish, since it often uses `w` and `y` (semivowels in English) as vowels. Same problem with `ij` in Dutch, which is a diphthong, not a vowel+consonant.

Comment: Do you have any idea what foreign languages might actually be present in the PDF text? If you at least know what character-sets they use, you can use that to catch some garbage, and if you have a corpus for each language available, you can use that get a pretty accurate idea of what's garbage and what's not.

Comment: Use a bigger dictionary!

Comment: The extracted text is bibliographic references. So the entire document is almost always English, but I could easily see them using foreign texts as sources. Although this *might* be infrequent enough that I can accept the false positives coming from foreign words. I'd definitely have to ignore proper names though.

Answer (score 2):

Hm, I imagine you could train a SVM or neural network on character n-grams...but you'd need pretty darn long ones.  The problem is that this would probably have a high rate of false negatives (throwing out what you wanted) because you can have *drastically* different rates of character clusters in various languages.

Take Polish, for example (it's my only second language in easy-to-type Latin characters).  `Skrzywdy` would be a highly unlikely series of letters in English, but is easily pronouncable in Polish.

A better technique might be to use language detection to detect languages used in a document above a certain probability, and then check the dictionaries for those languages...

This won't help for (for instance) a Linguistics textbook where a large variety of snippets of various languages are frequently used.

** EDIT **

Idea 2:

You say this is Bibliographic information. Meta-information like its position in the text or any font information your OCR software is returning to you is almost certainly *more* important than the series of characters you see showing up.  If it's in the title, or near the position where author goes, or in Italics, it's worth considering as foreign...

Comment: Interesting approach. Almost all of these are in English, but the section that I'm parsing out (bibliographic references) are probably *more* likely to have proper names and foreign words (from article titles and the authors) than the remaining text. So normally I think this'd work great but in this special use case probably not as well.

Comment: Hm, sounds like the 'linguistics textbook' scenario! ;) Lemme spin on it while I work out some other problem and see if I can come up with something else...